# Access-Control-Allow-Origin trouble with Mootools

Tags: controls

I've this error on my page but I can't solve it Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here is my code: I wrote this in my html file :

```
<div id="elapsed" data-url="http://myurl1.com/fr/chrono/">
```

And here is my:

```
var initChrono=function(){var e=$("dd"),t=$("hh"),n=$("mn"),r=$("ss"),i,s,o;(new Request.JSON({
    url: 'http://myurl1.com/fr/chrono/',
    callbackKey: 'callback',dataType: "jsonp",onSuccess:function(e){s=e.elapsed;o=e.status;a()}})).get();var a=function(u){i=s>0?"-":"";if(!u)s-=1;if(o==0){var l="00",c="00",p="00",v="00"}if(o==1||o==2){var g=Math.abs(s)
```

Can some help me?
I don't know how to work with this Jsonp

Answer (score 2):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin warnings in this case would mean the url you are trying to load is not in the same domain as the page making the request.

You are using Request.JSON in your code above when what you need is Request.JSONP. This method injects a script tag to load the content as javascript wrapped in a method named with the value of callbackKey:

```
 callback({ ... })
```

Your code example is incomplete and referencing undefined vars, so I am not entirely sure what you are doing here, but I think the request you are looking for is:

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://myurl1.com/fr/chrono/',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    onComplete: function(data){
        // do whatever
    }
}).send();
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GbTJp/

Mootools reference: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP

If you are also developing the page that returns the JSON, you will need to read up on 'returning JSONP' in whatever server-side language you are coding in. This page will need to check if the get var 'callback' has been set, and if so, wrap the JSON string in a method defined by 'callback', then return with Content-Type: text/javascript.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP